# Tamil Android Keyboard crashing except in google apps

Tags: android, android-service, custom-keyboard

I have created a Tamil keyboard using Android Service.

It is working perfectly in google apps. In all other apps it is crashing after typing 3 to 10 characters. 
If I copied the characters from google app and pasted in other apps it is not crashing even I typed the same string again. Again while deleting, it reaches that point and crashing.

I tried typing the string "தமிழுக்கு நிகர் ஏது". Always crashing at the point of typing "ஏ" and sometimes crashing at "நி,க,ர்"

In whatsapp I tried to enter tamil words. After giving space and if I started typing a new word, the previous last words last vowel is splitting from letter automatically. Attached screenshots below.
In google apps it is not happening(not splitting).

The app has only service to run. I can't enable debugger to find the crash.
I printed the code which is passing after typing the key. The codes are going properly and getting printed. Even last pressed code also going before crashing.

If anyone faced the same problem and you guys fixed, please share your experience.

[image: before start typing the second word]

[image: after started typing the word is like]

Code:
qwerty xml:

```
 <Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:keyWidth="10%p"
     android:horizontalGap="0px"
     android:verticalGap="0px"
     android:keyHeight="40dp"
     >
     ....<!--above rows-->
    <Row>
         <Key android:codes="2946" android:keyLabel="்" android:keyWidth="9%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="left"/>
         <Key android:codes="3006" android:keyLabel="ா"/>
         <Key android:codes="3007" android:keyLabel="ி" android:keyWidth="9%p"/>
         <Key android:codes="3008" android:keyLabel="ீ" android:keyWidth="9%p"/>
         <Key android:codes="3009" android:keyLabel="ு" android:keyWidth="9%p"/>
         <Key android:codes="3010" android:keyLabel="ூ" android:keyWidth="9%p"/>
         <Key android:codes="3014" android:keyLabel="ெ" android:keyWidth="11%p"/>
         <Key android:codes="3015" android:keyLabel="ே" android:keyWidth="11%p"/>
         <Key android:codes="3016" android:keyLabel="ை" android:keyWidth="11%p"/>
         <Key android:codes="2964" android:keyLabel="ஔ" android:keyWidth="12%p" android:keyEdgeFlags="right" />

         ....<!--bottom rows-->
     </Row>
 </Keyboard>
```

method xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <input-method xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <subtype
        android:label="@string/subtype_en_US"
        android:imeSubtypeLocale="en_US"
        android:imeSubtypeMode="keyboard" />
</input-method>
```

layout xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/keyboard"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:keyPreviewLayout ="@layout/preview"/>
```

Java class file:

```
 public class SimpleIME extends InputMethodService
    implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

private KeyboardView kv;
private Keyboard keyboard;

private boolean caps = false;

@Override
public View onCreateInputView() {
    kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
    keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
    kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    return kv;
}

private void playClick(int keyCode){
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
    switch(keyCode){
        case 32:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_SPACEBAR);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
        case 10:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_RETURN);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE:
            am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_DELETE);
            break;
        default: am.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEYPRESS_STANDARD);
    }
}


@Override
public void onKey(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
    playClick(primaryCode);
    switch(primaryCode){
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DELETE :
            ic.deleteSurroundingText(1, 0);
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_SHIFT:
            caps = !caps;
            keyboard.setShifted(caps);
            kv.invalidateAllKeys();
            break;
        case Keyboard.KEYCODE_DONE:
            ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
            break;
        default:
            char code = (char)primaryCode;
            if(Character.isLetter(code) && caps){
                code = Character.toUpperCase(code);
            }
            ic.commitText(String.valueOf(code),1);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: no can code in screenshots. please improve your question and add relevant code and identify your crash's stacktrace

Comment: so where is the code?

Comment: Edited the Question. @petey, It doesn't have launch activity. Only runs with Service. Stacktrace is not getting.

Comment: @AbishR  Report it as a bug. Update the relevant apps and check whether this issue is sorted out or not. It works well for me.

Comment: Thank you SibiCoder. It is crashing in whatsapp(Lenovo). In few devices it is not crashing at all. I don't know why. How to figure it out.